# Como utilizar o SQLite em uma aplicação Cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova, sqlite

Senhores, tenho um aplicativo híbrido que construí em HTML, CSS e JavaScript (JQuery Mobile) usando o Cordova, e agora eu gostaria de fazer acesso ao banco de dados do dispositivo. Infelizmente não sei por onde começar, pois nas pesquisas que fiz a maioria do material está em inglês (dale Google translate). Eu gostaria de um simples exemplo de CRUD para poder seguir e dicas para a iniciação como:

1. Tenho que dar permissão de acesso ao aplicativo para acessar o
   banco?
2. As informações guardadas permaneceram definitivamente no dispositivo?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma interface nativa sqlite no Cordova/PhoneGap

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

Exemplo:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

      var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });

      // for opening a background db:
      var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", bgType: 1 });

      $scope.execute = function() {
        var query = "INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test", 100]).then(function(res) {
          console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
      };

    });
```

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Comment: você está fazendo uma inserção na tabela mas não criou ela antes.... Eu tbm estou procurando uma boa explicação sobre como usar Cordova/SQLite, os tutoriais que vi não trouxeram soluções boas para coisas básicas. Se puder contribuir com uma solução completa seria muito bom. 

 Obrigado

Comment: Queria poder bater um papo com outros dev's que usam Ionic/Cordova/Phonegap. Se você puder, pode entrar em contato comigo pelo Skype: tiagofly@outlook.com. Abraço